# Bootstrap 4: keep fixed navbar stay in parent container-fluid

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

In the provided example the fixed navbar overlaps the spans about the the wrapper. Is it possible to make it span only over the content-wrapper/container-fluid? Can't find a working example.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
   ...
  </div>

  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
      </nav>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```